# save pdf file in iPhone with custom extension

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pdf, xcode4.2

I want to save .pdf file in iphone's document directory but with some custome extention.
i.e. Test.pdf file stored in documents directory as Test.pdf1. And also when I retrive that pdf file it will show me in proper pdf format. 
Please anybody having idea about it then please reply.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi I have tried to save Test.pdf as Test.pdf1 in documnets directory but then when I retrive it back it will change format of PDF file. SO It didnt works for me

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSString *oldPath = @".../123.pdf";
NSString *newPath = [[oldPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"123.pdf1"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:oldPath toPath:newPath error:nil];
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this snippet,but when I retrive it back it will change format of PDF file. SO It didnt works for me.

Comment: Actually I get blank page of PDF.So no PDFpage displayed.